# Transformation matrix to align an object towards a vector.

Tags: vectors, geometric-transformation

I have an object(say, a prism) in 3D space and a vector. I need to align this object in the direction of the given vector. What would be the transformation matrix required to achieve it? Assume that starting point of vector is (a,b,c) and end point is (x,y,z).

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748144/how-to-find-the-rotation-matrix-that-will-align-an-arbitrary-vector-to-an-axis?rq=1) but use your choice of axis rather than $e_y$ is used in that question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume aligning in this case means that the normal vector of the object points in the same direction as the desired vector. To this end, let's say that the vector $\pmb n$ is a normal vector of the object and also let's denote by $\pmb d$ (which is easily computed in terms of $x,y,z,a,b,c$) the desired vector. Your task is now to transform $\pmb n$ to a direction towards $\pmb d$, namely
$$\pmb n_t = \alpha \pmb d$$
for $\alpha \neq 0$. Here $\pmb n_t $ is the transformed $\pmb n$. All you need to do is to rotate $\pmb n$ to align with $\pmb d$. This could be achieved by cascaded Given rotation matrices, that is
$$\pmb n_t = G_x(\theta_x)G_y(\theta_y)G_z(\theta_z) \pmb n \tag{1}$$
where 
\begin{alignat}{1}
G_x(\theta_x) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta_x &  -\sin \theta_x \\[3pt]
0 & \sin \theta_x  &  \cos \theta_x \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
G_y(\theta_y) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_y & 0 & \sin \theta_y \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \theta_y & 0 & \cos \theta_y \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
G_z(\theta_z) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_z &  -\sin \theta_z & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta_z &   \cos \theta_z & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat}
where $G_t(\theta_t)$ denotes a given rotation about the $t-$axis, rotated by $\theta_t$. An example would be 
$$G_z(90^\circ) \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  $$
which means that you have rotated the x axis towards the y axis. Note that the operation in equation $(1)$ is commutative, that is it does not matter which rotation you start with.

Answer (score 0):

To align $\mathbf{a}$ with $\mathbf{d}$, assumed linearly independent, rotate about the axis $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{d}$ with an angle $\angle(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{d})=\arccos(\frac{\mathbf{a}}{\lvert\mathbf{a}\rvert}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{d}}{\lvert\mathbf{d}\rvert})$ (using the usual principle branch of arccos, angle between $0$ and $\pi$).

See the answer to [this question](/questions/748144) if you don't know how to do this (note that you need to normalise the axis vector first).

Comment: Using $\arccos$ introduces a directional ambiguity that neither this answer nor the linked one resolves. It’s better to construct the rotation matrix directly without computing the angle explicitly.

Comment: What directional ambiguity are you talking about?  I don't see any.

Comment: The standard $\arccos\colon [-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$

Comment: Cosines can’t tell left from right, but I was a bit hasty here—the cross product takes care of getting the correct orientation. I’d still avoid explicitly computing the angle in practice since one really needs its sine and cosine, and the former can be computed directly from the latter.