# Find orthogonal matrix Q

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix Q such that: 
$$Q \left[\begin{array}{r} 3\\ 0 \\ 4\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{r} 5\\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$$

How can I find matrix Q if I only know the info like above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/how-to-find-the-orthonormal-transformation-that-will-rotate-a-vector-to-the-x-ax

Comment: I don't quite understand those posts, can you please explain to me ?

Comment: since orthogonal matrix represents a rotation or refection, in 3D, there are two variables to control a rotate. they just did that. In you case, since the second term of vector does not change, you should only consider a matrix transferring $(3,4)'$ to $(5,0)'$.

Answer (score 1):

Since your second term of vector does not change. $A$ is in form of

$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &0& \sin\theta\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$

then just find out $\theta$.

$\cos \theta = 0.6$ and 
$\sin\theta = 0.8$

Comment: It would also be $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &0& -\sin\theta\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin\theta & 0 & -\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:
$$Q=I-\frac2{\bf d\cdot d}{\bf d}{\bf d}^T\quad\hbox{where}\quad
  {\bf d}=\pmatrix{3\cr0\cr4\cr}-\pmatrix{5\cr0\cr0\cr}\ .$$

Comment: The form of $Q$ above makes it a Householder Reflector: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation. Such matrices are nice because they are Hermitian, unitary, idempotent, and have unit magnitude eigenvalues.